# glpk model's different behaviour

Tags: model, glpk

My task is the following:

There are investors who want to invest in the stock market. We know the prices of stocks ahead for a given time and they have given amount of money to invest. Find a way to maximize the profit by the end of that time.

I try to make it so that as you add more investors to the set, it is like you run the model with only one investor but that many times.

E.g.(code below): If the set of **Investors** only consists of Oliver who have 100 money, the profit will be 3424. If the set of **Investors** only consists of Emma who have 150 money, the profit will be 5337. But if I put both of them in the set Oliver's profit will be 3424 but Emma's only 1979. My goal is it to be the same as if it was alone.

I think the problem is with the **maximize** function but I'm not sure.

```
param numberOfWeeks := 12;
set Weeks := 1..numberOfWeeks;
set Stocks;
set Investors;
param priceOfStocks{Stocks, Weeks};
param HowMuchCanInvest{Investors};

# Buying is a positive number, selling is negative
var buySell{Stocks, Weeks, Investors} integer;

s.t. CannotSpendMoreThanWeHave{w in Weeks, i in Investors}:
    sum{w2 in 1..w, s in Stocks} buySell[s, w2, i] * priceOfStocks[s, w2] <= HowMuchCanInvest[i];

s.t. OnlySellStocksWeHave{w in Weeks, s in Stocks, i in Investors}:
    sum{w2 in 1..w} buySell[s, w2, i] >= 0;

maximize ProfitAtTheEnd{i in Investors}:
    0 - (sum{w in Weeks, s in Stocks} buySell[s, w, i] * priceOfStocks[s, w]);

solve;


for{i in Investors}{
    printf "%s\n", i;
    for{w in Weeks}{
        printf "Week %d", w, "\n";
        
        printf "\tBuy: ";
        for{s in Stocks: buySell[s, w, i] > 0}{
            printf "%s(%d)", s, buySell[s, w, i];
        }
        
        printf "\n";
        
        printf "\tSell: ";
        for{s in Stocks: buySell[s, w, i] < 0}{
            printf "%s(%d)", s, -buySell[s, w, i];
        }
        
        printf "\n";
    }
    printf "%s: %d", i, ProfitAtTheEnd[i];
    printf "\n";
}

data;

set Stocks := OTP MOL AMZN GOOGL FB TSLA NFLX AAPL MSFT NVDA;

param priceOfStocks:
            1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12 :=
OTP         10      11      12      11      14      16      9       25      22      18      19      21
MOL         52      54      51      59      48      55      57      61      56      60      62      56
AMZN        36      39      41      40      38      42      37      40      43      48      46      37
GOOGL       20      18      16      17      19      21      23      22      24      28      26      27
FB          8       9       10      15      13      14      17      18      16      9       19      17
TSLA        25      22      24      28      31      30      33      32      30      29      33      34
NFLX        44      48      51      50      50      52      47      53      55      54      58      53
AAPL        88      85      83      84      80      78      77      81      84      86      82      81
MSFT        64      68      69      71      72      70      68      65      63      67      70      74
NVDA        15      19      17      21      25      29      23      18      20      16      17      22
;

set Investors := Oliver Emma /*Jack*/ ;

param HowMuchCanInvest :=
    Oliver      100
    Emma        150
    /*Jack      200*/
;

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

GLPK allows only a single term to be maximized. ProfitAtTheEnd should not be indexed instead you have to sum the profit over the investors in your target function.

As solution time is not linear with the number of investors putting them all in one model does not make any sense. You should instead use a script to call GLPK repeatedly with different data sets.